# Permanent Webpage Background in CSS

Tags: html, css, background

I currently am working on a basic website for a friend who wants a simple blog/website, and have a quick CSS question.

http://nashread.com/template1 Is the current domain, and if the background on there is fine and covers the whole screen. That's because the content box isn't long enough to extend the page. If you click on the 'blogs' tab, you'll see that if the content box extends the background, it just goes into white space. Basically what I'm asking, is how would I make it so when you scroll it only scrolls the content box, rather than the whole webpage? It might not even be possible in HTML or CSS, so if so please tell me.

Thanks (=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following changes in your css I hope it will work for you. Instead of the position absolute I have changed it to position fixed.

```
#background {
    background: url("pics/bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked! I knew it was going to be something simple like that.. will rate as answer in a few (=

Comment: I am looking your blog page......there are more unnecessary tags you are using for space. Like you have some blank p tag(<p></p>). For spacing you can use padding. And for blog post you can arrange it in ul and li. So instead of hr you can use bottom-border in li and instead blank p tag you give padding-bottom and margin-bottom in li.